# c# windows forms application Pinning start location when button clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, persistence

I have made a new windows forms application, and I'm trying to use a button to allow the user to save the application startup location when the button is clicked. I have tried to look the problem up, but I can't find anything about using a button to do it.

Here is what I have found so far which saves the location on the screen when the form is closed, I just don't know how to make it only save the location when a button is clicked:

```
public static void GeometryFromString(string thisWindowGeometry, Form formIn)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisWindowGeometry) == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    string[] numbers = thisWindowGeometry.Split('|');
    string windowString = numbers[4];
    if (windowString == "Normal")
    {
        Point windowPoint = new Point(int.Parse(numbers[0]),
            int.Parse(numbers[1]));
        Size windowSize = new Size(int.Parse(numbers[2]),
            int.Parse(numbers[3]));

        bool locOkay = GeometryIsBizarreLocation(windowPoint, windowSize);
        bool sizeOkay = GeometryIsBizarreSize(windowSize);

        if (locOkay == true && sizeOkay == true)
        {
            formIn.Location = windowPoint;
            formIn.Size = windowSize;
            formIn.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            formIn.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        else if (sizeOkay == true)
        {
            formIn.Size = windowSize;
        }
    }
    else if (windowString == "Maximized")
    {
        formIn.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        formIn.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        formIn.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
private static bool GeometryIsBizarreLocation(Point loc, Size size)
{
    bool locOkay;
    if (loc.X < 0 || loc.Y < 0)
    {
        locOkay = false;
    }
    else if (loc.X + size.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width)
    {
        locOkay = false;
    }
    else if (loc.Y + size.Height > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height)
    {
        locOkay = false;
    }
    else
    {
        locOkay = true;
    }
    return locOkay;
}
private static bool GeometryIsBizarreSize(Size size)
{
    return (size.Height <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height &&
        size.Width <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width);
}
public static string GeometryToString(Form mainForm)
{
    return mainForm.Location.X.ToString() + "|" +
        mainForm.Location.Y.ToString() + "|" +
        mainForm.Size.Width.ToString() + "|" +
        mainForm.Size.Height.ToString() + "|" +
        mainForm.WindowState.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *application startup location*? Are you referring to the starting Form's bounds?

Comment: To add to Jimi's comment, it sounds like you've found a way to save the application startup location (whatever that means) but you don't know how to trigger it using a button click? Is that correct? If so then [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74706819/edit) your question to include what you know so far would help us to answer.

Comment: I just added the code I have found to the question I initialy posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of many ways to implement a button to save the `Location` (and optionally `Size`).

[image: screenshot]

---

First, Create a Settings resource if one doesn't already exist. Right-click on the Project and select Properties.

[image: project]

Choose the `Settings` tab and click the link to create the resource.

[image: link]

Make entries for Size and Location:

[image: entries]

---

Add a `Click` handler for your `Save` button:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    buttonSaveSizeAndPosition.Click += saveSizeAndPosition;
}

private async void saveSizeAndPosition(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Location = Location;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Size = Size;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    var textB4 = Text;
    Text = $"Location = {Location} Size = {Size}";
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Text = textB4;
}
```

---

Then, when you load the main form check to see whether the `Size` has moved off of the default value before reloading these properties:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (!Properties.Settings.Default.Size.Equals(new Size()))
    {
        Location = Properties.Settings.Default.Location;
        Size = Properties.Settings.Default.Size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will I need to add anything to my events properties, such as the Load event, or Form Closing Event

Comment: The event is added in the line that says `buttonSaveSizeAndPosition.Click += saveSizeAndPosition` but adding it in the Designer would work the same.

Comment: Here's the code I used to test my answer if you want to [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/persist-start-location.git) it from GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/Csumner1027/Psp-Kanban,  Here is the project I am working on, I am very, very new to programming. I have tried to implement the code you have into it, its not throwing any errors, its just not saving the start locaton, Could you by any chance take a look at it and see if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: One of the requirements for the project was that I have to use a tool strip menu with a button in the tool strip menu as the Save Size and Position button, I'll add a picture of it to the repository. Thank you very much for all of your help

Comment: I've named it "pinStartLocationToolStripMenuItem_Click"

Comment: You code works fine with a couple problems fixed. #1 (critical) Your `OnLoad` is missing `Location = Properties.Settings.Default.Location` like in my post. #2 (critical) you subscribed `saveSizeAndPosition` to the OnLoad event. If it calls it during load, it's going to overwrite whatever you have saved, isn't it? #3 (not optimal) You subscribed `saveSizeAndPosition` to `LocationChanged` event which is going to call it hundreds of times during a move. #4 (not optimal) You subscribed `saveSizeAndPosition` to `FormClosing` which is fine but then why have a tool bar option at all?

Comment: Finally! It works! I cant thank you enough for all of your help! Your are truly a life Saver. Been scratching my head for three days,lol.